# How to disable the selected and previous date in moment js calendar..?

Tags: javascript, html, date, calendar, momentjs

I'm integrating calender in one of project using moment js.

I want to disable previous date and some other selected date.

I tried but date is not disabled.

Here is my javascript code,

```js
!function() {

  var today = moment();

  function Calendar(selector, events) {
    this.el = document.querySelector(selector);
    this.events = events;
    this.current = moment().date(1);
    this.draw();
    var current = document.querySelector('.today');
    if(current) {
      var self = this;
      window.setTimeout(function() {
        self.openDay(current);
      }, 500);
    }
  }

  Calendar.prototype.draw = function() {
    //Create Header
    this.drawHeader();

    //Draw Month
    this.drawMonth();

    this.drawLegend();
  }

  Calendar.prototype.drawHeader = function() {
    var self = this;
    if(!this.header) {
      //Create the header elements
      this.header = createElement('div', 'header');
      this.header.className = 'header';

      this.title = createElement('h1');

      var right = createElement('div', 'right');
      right.addEventListener('click', function() { self.nextMonth(); });

      var left = createElement('div', 'left');
      left.addEventListener('click', function() { self.prevMonth(); });

      //Append the Elements
      this.header.appendChild(this.title); 
      this.header.appendChild(right);
      this.header.appendChild(left);
      this.el.appendChild(this.header);
    }

    this.title.innerHTML = this.current.format('MMMM YYYY');
  }

  Calendar.prototype.drawMonth = function() {
    var self = this;
    
    this.events.forEach(function(ev) {
     ev.date = self.current.clone().date(Math.random() * (29 - 1) + 1);
    });
    
    
    if(this.month) {
      this.oldMonth = this.month;
      this.oldMonth.className = 'month out ' + (self.next ? 'next' : 'prev');
      this.oldMonth.addEventListener('webkitAnimationEnd', function() {
        self.oldMonth.parentNode.removeChild(self.oldMonth);
        self.month = createElement('div', 'month');
        self.backFill();
        self.currentMonth();
        self.fowardFill();
        self.el.appendChild(self.month);
        window.setTimeout(function() {
          self.month.className = 'month in ' + (self.next ? 'next' : 'prev');
        }, 16);
      });
    } else {
        this.month = createElement('div', 'month');
        this.el.appendChild(this.month);
        this.backFill();
        this.currentMonth();
        this.fowardFill();
        this.month.className = 'month new';
    }
  }

  Calendar.prototype.backFill = function() {
    var clone = this.current.clone();
    var dayOfWeek = clone.day();

    if(!dayOfWeek) { return; }

    clone.subtract('days', dayOfWeek+1);

    for(var i = dayOfWeek; i > 0 ; i--) {
      this.drawDay(clone.add('days', 1));
    }
  }

  Calendar.prototype.fowardFill = function() {
    var clone = this.current.clone().add('months', 1).subtract('days', 1);
    var dayOfWeek = clone.day();

    if(dayOfWeek === 6) { return; }

    for(var i = dayOfWeek; i < 6 ; i++) {
      this.drawDay(clone.add('days', 1));
    }
  }

  Calendar.prototype.currentMonth = function() {
    var clone = this.current.clone();

    while(clone.month() === this.current.month()) {
      this.drawDay(clone);
      clone.add('days', 1);
    }
  }

  Calendar.prototype.getWeek = function(day) {
    if(!this.week || day.day() === 0) {
      this.week = createElement('div', 'week');
      this.month.appendChild(this.week);
    }
  }

  Calendar.prototype.drawDay = function(day) {
    var self = this;
    this.getWeek(day);

    //Outer Day
    var outer = createElement('div', this.getDayClass(day));
    outer.addEventListener('click', function() {
      self.openDay(this);
    });

    //Day Name
    var name = createElement('div', 'day-name', day.format('ddd'));

    //Day Number
    var number = createElement('div', 'day-number', day.format('DD'));


    //Events
    var events = createElement('div', 'day-events');
    this.drawEvents(day, events);

    outer.appendChild(name);
    outer.appendChild(number);
    outer.appendChild(events);
    this.week.appendChild(outer);
  }

  Calendar.prototype.drawEvents = function(day, element) {
    if(day.month() === this.current.month()) {
      var todaysEvents = this.events.reduce(function(memo, ev) {
        if(ev.date.isSame(day, 'day')) {
          memo.push(ev);
        }
        return memo;
      }, []);

      todaysEvents.forEach(function(ev) {
        var evSpan = createElement('span', ev.color);
        element.appendChild(evSpan);
      });
    }
  }

  Calendar.prototype.getDayClass = function(day) {
    classes = ['day'];
    if(day.month() !== this.current.month()) {
      classes.push('other');
    } else if (today.isSame(day, 'day')) {
      classes.push('today');
    }
    return classes.join(' ');
  }

  Calendar.prototype.openDay = function(el) {
    var details, arrow;
    var dayNumber = +el.querySelectorAll('.day-number')[0].innerText || +el.querySelectorAll('.day-number')[0].textContent;
    var day = this.current.clone().date(dayNumber);

    var currentOpened = document.querySelector('.details');

    //Check to see if there is an open detais box on the current row
    if(currentOpened && currentOpened.parentNode === el.parentNode) {
      details = currentOpened;
      arrow = document.querySelector('.arrow');
    } else {
      //Close the open events on differnt week row
      //currentOpened && currentOpened.parentNode.removeChild(currentOpened);
      if(currentOpened) {
        currentOpened.addEventListener('webkitAnimationEnd', function() {
          currentOpened.parentNode.removeChild(currentOpened);
        });
        currentOpened.addEventListener('oanimationend', function() {
          currentOpened.parentNode.removeChild(currentOpened);
        });
        currentOpened.addEventListener('msAnimationEnd', function() {
          currentOpened.parentNode.removeChild(currentOpened);
        });
        currentOpened.addEventListener('animationend', function() {
          currentOpened.parentNode.removeChild(currentOpened);
        });
        currentOpened.className = 'details out';
      }

      //Create the Details Container
      details = createElement('div', 'details in');

      //Create the arrow
      var arrow = createElement('div', 'arrow');

      //Create the event wrapper

      details.appendChild(arrow);
      el.parentNode.appendChild(details);
    }

    var todaysEvents = this.events.reduce(function(memo, ev) {
      if(ev.date.isSame(day, 'day')) {
        memo.push(ev);
      }
      return memo;
    }, []);

    this.renderEvents(todaysEvents, details);

    arrow.style.left = el.offsetLeft - el.parentNode.offsetLeft + 27 + 'px';
  }

  Calendar.prototype.renderEvents = function(events, ele) {
    //Remove any events in the current details element
    var currentWrapper = ele.querySelector('.events');
    var wrapper = createElement('div', 'events in' + (currentWrapper ? ' new' : ''));

    events.forEach(function(ev) {
      var div = createElement('div', 'event');
      var square = createElement('div', 'event-category ' + ev.color);
      var span = createElement('span', '', ev.eventName);

      div.appendChild(square);
      div.appendChild(span);
      wrapper.appendChild(div);
    });

    if(!events.length) {
      var div = createElement('div', 'event empty');
      var span = createElement('span', '', 'No Events');

      div.appendChild(span);
      wrapper.appendChild(div);
    }

    if(currentWrapper) {
      currentWrapper.className = 'events out';
      currentWrapper.addEventListener('webkitAnimationEnd', function() {
        currentWrapper.parentNode.removeChild(currentWrapper);
        ele.appendChild(wrapper);
      });
      currentWrapper.addEventListener('oanimationend', function() {
        currentWrapper.parentNode.removeChild(currentWrapper);
        ele.appendChild(wrapper);
      });
      currentWrapper.addEventListener('msAnimationEnd', function() {
        currentWrapper.parentNode.removeChild(currentWrapper);
        ele.appendChild(wrapper);
      });
      currentWrapper.addEventListener('animationend', function() {
        currentWrapper.parentNode.removeChild(currentWrapper);
        ele.appendChild(wrapper);
      });
    } else {
      ele.appendChild(wrapper);
    }
  }

  Calendar.prototype.drawLegend = function() {
    var legend = createElement('div', 'legend');
    var calendars = this.events.map(function(e) {
      return e.calendar + '|' + e.color;
    }).reduce(function(memo, e) {
      if(memo.indexOf(e) === -1) {
        memo.push(e);
      }
      return memo;
    }, []).forEach(function(e) {
      var parts = e.split('|');
      var entry = createElement('span', 'entry ' +  parts[1], parts[0]);
      legend.appendChild(entry);
    });
    this.el.appendChild(legend);
  }

  Calendar.prototype.nextMonth = function() {
    this.current.add('months', 1);
    this.next = true;
    this.draw();
  }

  Calendar.prototype.prevMonth = function() {
    this.current.subtract('months', 1);
    this.next = false;
    this.draw();
  }

  window.Calendar = Calendar;

  function createElement(tagName, className, innerText) {
    var ele = document.createElement(tagName);
    if(className) {
      ele.className = className;
    }
    if(innerText) {
      ele.innderText = ele.textContent = innerText;
    }
    return ele;
  }
}();

!function() {
  var data = [
    { eventName: 'Lunch Meeting w/ Mark', calendar: 'Work', color: 'orange' },
    { eventName: 'Interview - Jr. Web Developer', calendar: 'Work', color: 'orange' },
    { eventName: 'Demo New App to the Board', calendar: 'Work', color: 'orange' },
    { eventName: 'Dinner w/ Marketing', calendar: 'Work', color: 'orange' },

    { eventName: 'Game vs Portalnd', calendar: 'Sports', color: 'blue' },
    { eventName: 'Game vs Houston', calendar: 'Sports', color: 'blue' },
    { eventName: 'Game vs Denver', calendar: 'Sports', color: 'blue' },
    { eventName: 'Game vs San Degio', calendar: 'Sports', color: 'blue' },

    { eventName: 'School Play', calendar: 'Kids', color: 'yellow' },
    { eventName: 'Parent/Teacher Conference', calendar: 'Kids', color: 'yellow' },
    { eventName: 'Pick up from Soccer Practice', calendar: 'Kids', color: 'yellow' },
    { eventName: 'Ice Cream Night', calendar: 'Kids', color: 'yellow' },

    { eventName: 'Free Tamale Night', calendar: 'Other', color: 'green' },
    { eventName: 'Bowling Team', calendar: 'Other', color: 'green' },
    { eventName: 'Teach Kids to Code', calendar: 'Other', color: 'green' },
    { eventName: 'Startup Weekend', calendar: 'Other', color: 'green' }
  ];

  

  function addDate(ev) {
    
  }

  var calendar = new Calendar('#calendar', data);

}();
```

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
-moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
 overflow: hidden;
 font-family: 'HelveticaNeue-UltraLight', 'Helvetica Neue UltraLight', 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-weight: 100;
 color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 background: #4A4A4A;
 -webkit-touch-callout: none;
 -webkit-user-select: none;
 -khtml-user-select: none;
 -moz-user-select: none;
 -ms-user-select: none;
 user-select: none;
}

#calendar {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  width: 420px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 570px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.header {
  height: 50px;
  width: 420px;
  background: rgba(66, 66, 66, 1);
  text-align: center;
  position:relative;
  z-index: 100;
}

.header h1 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-weight: 100;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.left, .right {
  position: absolute;
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  border-style: solid;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -7.5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.left {
  border-width: 7.5px 10px 7.5px 0;
  border-color: transparent rgba(160, 159, 160, 1) transparent transparent;
  left: 20px;
}

.right {
  border-width: 7.5px 0 7.5px 10px;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent rgba(160, 159, 160, 1);
  right: 20px;
}

.month {
  /*overflow: hidden;*/
  opacity: 0;
}

.month.new {
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s ease-out;
  opacity: 1;
}

.month.in.next {
  -webkit-animation: moveFromTopFadeMonth .4s ease-out;
  -moz-animation: moveFromTopFadeMonth .4s ease-out;
  animation: moveFromTopFadeMonth .4s ease-out;
  opacity: 1;
}

.month.out.next {
  -webkit-animation: moveToTopFadeMonth .4s ease-in;
  -moz-animation: moveToTopFadeMonth .4s ease-in;
  animation: moveToTopFadeMonth .4s ease-in;
  opacity: 1;
}

.month.in.prev {
  -webkit-animation: moveFromBottomFadeMonth .4s ease-out;
  -moz-animation: moveFromBottomFadeMonth .4s ease-out;
  animation: moveFromBottomFadeMonth .4s ease-out;
  opacity: 1;
}

.month.out.prev {
  -webkit-animation: moveToBottomFadeMonth .4s ease-in;
  -moz-animation: moveToBottomFadeMonth .4s ease-in;
  animation: moveToBottomFadeMonth .4s ease-in;
  opacity: 1;
}

.week {
 background: #4A4A4A;
}

.day {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: top;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #4A4A4A;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100;
}

.day.other {
 color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .3);
}

.day.today {
  color: rgba(156, 202, 235, 1);
}

.day-name {
  font-size: 9px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
  letter-spacing: .7px;
}

.day-number {
  font-size: 24px;
  letter-spacing: 1.5px;
}


.day .day-events {
  list-style: none;
  margin-top: 3px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 12px;
  line-height: 6px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.day .day-events span {
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  line-height: 5px;
  margin: 0 1px;
}

.blue { background: rgba(156, 202, 235, 1); }
.orange { background: rgba(247, 167, 0, 1); }
.green { background: rgba(153, 198, 109, 1); }
.yellow { background: rgba(249, 233, 0, 1); }

.details {
  position: relative;
  width: 420px;
  height: 75px;
  background: rgba(164, 164, 164, 1);
  margin-top: 5px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.details.in {
  -webkit-animation: moveFromTopFade .5s ease both;
  -moz-animation: moveFromTopFade .5s ease both;
  animation: moveFromTopFade .5s ease both;
}

.details.out {
  -webkit-animation: moveToTopFade .5s ease both;
  -moz-animation: moveToTopFade .5s ease both;
  animation: moveToTopFade .5s ease both;
}

.arrow {
  position: absolute;
  top: -5px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -2px;
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 5px 5px 5px;
  border-color: transparent transparent rgba(164, 164, 164, 1) transparent;
  transition: all 0.7s ease;
}

.events {
  height: 75px;
  padding: 7px 0;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.events.in {
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn .3s ease both;
  -moz-animation: fadeIn .3s ease both;
  animation: fadeIn .3s ease both;
}

.events.in {
  -webkit-animation-delay: .3s;
  -moz-animation-delay: .3s;
  animation-delay: .3s;
}

.details.out .events {
  -webkit-animation: fadeOutShrink .4s ease both;
  -moz-animation: fadeOutShink .4s ease both;
  animation: fadeOutShink .4s ease both;
}

.events.out {
  -webkit-animation: fadeOut .3s ease both;
  -moz-animation: fadeOut .3s ease both;
  animation: fadeOut .3s ease both;
}

.event {
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 22px;
  letter-spacing: .5px;
  padding: 2px 16px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.event.empty {
  color: #eee;
}

.event-category {
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 6px 0 0;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.event span {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 0 0 7px;
}

.legend {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  background: rgba(60, 60, 60, 1);
  line-height: 30px;

}

.entry {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 0 0 25px;
  font-size: 13px;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 30px;
  background: transparent;
}

.entry:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  height: 5px;
  width: 5px;
  top: 12px;
  left: 14px;
}

.entry.blue:after { background: rgba(156, 202, 235, 1); }
.entry.orange:after { background: rgba(247, 167, 0, 1); }
.entry.green:after { background: rgba(153, 198, 109, 1); }
.entry.yellow:after { background: rgba(249, 233, 0, 1); }

/* Animations are cool!  */
@-webkit-keyframes moveFromTopFade {
  from { opacity: .3; height:0px; margin-top:0px; -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%); }
}
@-moz-keyframes moveFromTopFade {
  from { height:0px; margin-top:0px; -moz-transform: translateY(-100%); }
}
@keyframes moveFromTopFade {
  from { height:0px; margin-top:0px; transform: translateY(-100%); }
}

@-webkit-keyframes moveToTopFade {
  to { opacity: .3; height:0px; margin-top:0px; opacity: 0.3; -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%); }
}
@-moz-keyframes moveToTopFade {
  to { height:0px; -moz-transform: translateY(-100%); }
}
@keyframes moveToTopFade {
  to { height:0px; transform: translateY(-100%); }
}

@-webkit-keyframes moveToTopFadeMonth {
  to { opacity: 0; -webkit-transform: translateY(-30%) scale(.95); }
}
@-moz-keyframes moveToTopFadeMonth {
  to { opacity: 0; -moz-transform: translateY(-30%); }
}
@keyframes moveToTopFadeMonth {
  to { opacity: 0; -moz-transform: translateY(-30%); }
}

@-webkit-keyframes moveFromTopFadeMonth {
  from { opacity: 0; -webkit-transform: translateY(30%) scale(.95); }
}
@-moz-keyframes moveFromTopFadeMonth {
  from { opacity: 0; -moz-transform: translateY(30%); }
}
@keyframes moveFromTopFadeMonth {
  from { opacity: 0; -moz-transform: translateY(30%); }
}

@-webkit-keyframes moveToBottomFadeMonth {
  to { opacity: 0; -webkit-transform: translateY(30%) scale(.95); }
}
@-moz-keyframes moveToBottomFadeMonth {
  to { opacity: 0; -webkit-transform: translateY(30%); }
}
@keyframes moveToBottomFadeMonth {
  to { opacity: 0; -webkit-transform: translateY(30%); }
}

@-webkit-keyframes moveFromBottomFadeMonth {
  from { opacity: 0; -webkit-transform: translateY(-30%) scale(.95); }
}
@-moz-keyframes moveFromBottomFadeMonth {
  from { opacity: 0; -webkit-transform: translateY(-30%); }
}
@keyframes moveFromBottomFadeMonth {
  from { opacity: 0; -webkit-transform: translateY(-30%); }
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn  {
  from { opacity: 0; }
}
@-moz-keyframes fadeIn  {
  from { opacity: 0; }
}
@keyframes fadeIn  {
  from { opacity: 0; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeOut  {
  to { opacity: 0; }
}
@-moz-keyframes fadeOut  {
  to { opacity: 0; }
}
@keyframes fadeOut  {
  to { opacity: 0; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeOutShink  {
  to { opacity: 0; padding: 0px; height: 0px; }
}
@-moz-keyframes fadeOutShink  {
  to { opacity: 0; padding: 0px; height: 0px; }
}
@keyframes fadeOutShink  {
  to { opacity: 0; padding: 0px; height: 0px; }
}
```

```html
<div id="calendar"></div>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.5.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

I tried to disabling date but, it doesn't work. Can you guys please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Setup

In this answer, I'll disect multiple scenarios of yours, using several demos. Each of these have in common the fact that they're adding a `disabled` class on some days. I won't repeat this in every demo, so here it is, once:

**Inside `Calendar.prototype.drawDay`**

```
//Outer Day
var outer = createElement('div', this.getDayClass(day));
outer.addEventListener('click', function() {
  // Only open if the element is not disabled
  if (!this.classList.contains('disabled')) {
    self.openDay(this);
  }
});
```

**At the end of your CSS**

```
.day.disabled {
  color: #888;
  cursor: default;
}
```

## Disabling previous dates

You can use MomentJS's [`isBefore`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-before/) method to determine which days are past and should be disabled, and disable clicks on them.

```
/* ... */

Calendar.prototype.getDayClass = function(day) {
  classes = ['day'];
  if(day.month() !== this.current.month()) {
    classes.push('other');
  } else if (today.isSame(day, 'day')) {
    classes.push('today');
  }
  // Here, add a class to disable past dates
  if (day.isBefore(moment(), 'day')) {
    classes.push('disabled');
  }
  return classes.join(' ');
}

/* ... */
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/o53rnu4p/) *(I had to remove it from SO, too many characters)*

### Disabling all dates, except for some defined in an Array

Here, we're going to define an Array containing dates, and use that Array to decide whether or not to disable dates. The dates in your Array can be of any format, but you need to match that format when looking for a date in that Array.

In my example, I use the `YYYY-MM-DD` format (you can find other formats [**here**](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/))

```
/* Have this, somewhere in your code */

var allowedDates = [
  '2018-04-14',
  '2018-05-01',
  '2018-05-02'
  /* ... */
];

/* ... */

Calendar.prototype.getDayClass = function(day) {
  classes = ['day'];
  if(day.month() !== this.current.month()) {
    classes.push('other');
  } else if (today.isSame(day, 'day')) {
    classes.push('today');
  }
  // Here, add a class to disable disallowed dates
  if (allowedDates.indexOf(day.format('YYYY-MM-DD')) < 0) {
    classes.push('disabled');
  }
  return classes.join(' ');
}

/* ... */
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/wxb9j1yc/)

Comment: Its working but, in case i want only disable some months particular date so, what should i do..?

Comment: @K-Series Do you want to disable a month/date only once, or for every year? (e.g. december of every year) ?

Comment: No i want to disabled all date Except of my particular date.(particular dates is getting from json).

Comment: @K-Series I've updated my answer to only enable some dates, taken from an Array (I don't know what your JSON looks like, so you may need to make some adjustments)

Comment: Hello blex, I have another query regarding this calendar.I want to display data(eventName) based on particular date.Could you please help me to tackle this issue..?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168987/discussion-between-k-series-and-blex).

Comment: @K-Series I'm not sure I understand your request. Maybe you should create another question, with more details, and I'll try to answer it, with others :)

Comment: Hello here is my question please check : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49850374/how-to-get-event-name-on-click-particular-date-using-moment-js-calendar

Comment: you understand my question.?

Comment: @K-Series I’m leaving for work now, but I’ll have a look when I get back, if others didn’t answer in the meantime