# How to disable current month date and furture date in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

How to disable current month date and future date in JavaScript?
here is my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-ptolemy-rj3lc

As current month is `jan` so I want to disable `jan-2020` to all future dates `Feb-2020 ...dec-2020`

```
<DatePicker
      onChange={onChange}
      disabledDate={current => {
        console.log(moment().month());
        console.log(current.month());

        return moment().month() >= current.month();
      }}
    />
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49818429/how-to-disable-the-selected-and-previous-date-in-moment-js-calendar you should be able to change the disable previous dates to future dates pretty easily.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `isSameOrAfter` of `moment`

```
<DatePicker
  onChange={onChange}
  disabledDate={current => current.isSameOrAfter(moment(), 'month')}
/>
```

Docs: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-same-or-after/